Do I need websockets for sendAndConfirmTransaction() in web3.js version 2?
Do I need websockets for sendAndConfirmTransaction()?
In web3.js version 1, a websocket connection wasn't necessary. However in V2, sendAndConfirmTransactionFactory() requires an rpcSubscriptions argument which is a websocket.
import { createDefaultRpcTransport, createSolanaRpcFromTransport, createSolanaRpcSubscriptions, sendAndConfirmTransactionFactory } from "@solana/web3.js";

const transport = createDefaultRpcTransport({
  url: "http://127.0.0.1:8899",
});

// Create an RPC client using that transport.
const rpc = createSolanaRpcFromTransport(transport);

const rpcSubscriptions = createSolanaRpcSubscriptions("ws://127.0.0.1:8900");
const sendAndConfirmTransaction = sendAndConfirmTransactionFactory({
  rpc,
  rpcSubscriptions,
});


Both versions subscribe for signature status updates to know when a transaction is confirmed.

v1.x: (link)
v2.x: (link)

Version 2.x takes it one step further. Confirmation needs to detect when the transaction has expired because of its blockhash falling out of the status cache. 2.x does this by subscribing for slot updates) instead of polling the server for the blockheight as web3.js 1 did. Much faster, and lighter on the server.

Thanks - I suspected it had switched from a poll to a subscribe model (so actually had a need for the websockets) but hadn't seen this in the notes anywhere so wasn't entirely sure.

You're right, in web3.js version 2, sendAndConfirmTransactionFactory() requires rpcSubscriptions, which is a websocket connection. This is used to subscribe to events and confirmations in real-time, ensuring that transactions are properly tracked and confirmed.

I guess my question was hoping for: why? Since websockets weren't required in web3.js v1.

They were required in both implementations. Here is where the signature subscription is made in version 1.x: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/maintenance/v1.x/src/connection.ts#L3920-L3931

@steveluscher huh odd. I've never bothered with the websocket in 1.x before and I was able to confirm transactions. ‍♂️

Version 1.x doesn't give you a choice, @mikemaccana. It hot-replaces the https? with wss? at runtime and makes a websocket connection to confirm the transaction whether you like it or not.

Got it - thanks @steveluscher!
